# React hook useState not updating onclick

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I am trying to update the sidebar class when the `closehandler` function is called but the state is not updating. How do I go about that.

```
function RiderSidebar({ sidebar, close }) {

const [SidebarClass, setSidebarClass] = useState('sidebar')

const closeHandler = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("closed click");
    setSidebarClass("user-side-bar close")
    console.log("slidebar is " + SidebarClass);

    setTimeout(() => {
        close()
    }, 1000)
}
return (
    <div className={SidebarClass} >
        <button className="close-btn" onClick={closeHandler}>X</button>

        <ul>
            <li><NavLink to='/rider/dashboard' className="user-nav"  ><DashboardIcon />  Dashboard</NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink to='/rider/orders' className="user-nav"  ><HistoryIcon /> Orders</NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink to='/user/logout' className="user-nav"  ><PowerSettingsNewIcon /> Logout</NavLink></li>
        </ul>
    </div >
)
}
```

Comment: you mean it is not update in `console.log`?

Comment: ```but the state is not updating``` - Please explain, where are you checking this?

Comment: @DiwakarSingh when I click the close button if I check using the console.log on closeHandler function. but it displays sidebar on the console.

Comment: @nnam4x React batches the state update. If you will check the state update immediately after updating the state react then you may not get the updated state. You can check the updated state in render method. Please verify that you get the updated state there or not?

Comment: @DiwakarSingh yea it is updating on the render. Thank you

Comment: @nnam4x You are welcome. I have updated this comment as the answer for community. Please accept and upvote if this solves your issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React batches the state update. If you will check the state update immediately after updating the state react then you may not get the updated state. You can check the updated state in render method. It should be updated there.

Answer (score 4):

I think you add `useEffect` hooks to check  I explain briefly what did you wrong
when you click your **close button** closed handler function trigger and `setState` function calling at the same time(**asynchronous**) `console.log` statement printed. `//'side bar'`

in your code, you can't verify your state change or not (only you can verify from the render method) because the **closed handler function** triggers only one time if you want to check your `className` is changed or not from `console.log` statement you must need `useEffect` hook it will trigger every time after your `state` changed so can conform it your `className` is changed or not

```
//only trigger one time 
 useEffect(()=>{
 console.log(SidebarClass);//output 'sidebar'
 },[])
        
 //hooks trigger every time after your state changed
  useEffect(()=>{
 console.log(SidebarClass); 
 //output 'sidebar' 
 //output user-side-bar close
            })
        
 //only trigger if SidebarClass state changed
 useEffect(()=>{
 console.log(SidebarClass);
 //output 'sidebar' 
 //output user-side-bar close
 },[SidebarClass]);
```

Answer (score 0):

useState hook is asynchronous, and will not be reflected immediately..  try this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    
    }, [SidebarClass]);
```